# How to get type of data from external source

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I am using React and typescript with coinAPI. I have a question how can I get type of data. Because now I use  type unknown and I can not use the data inside my project. What to do?

```
const SearchForm: React.FC<funcProps> = (props) => {
  const [assetName, setAssetName] = useState<string>("");
  const onChangeInputHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setAssetName(e.target.value);
  };
  const onSearchSubmitHandler = async () => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/${assetName}`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CoinAPI-Key": "key",
          },
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      props.setAsset(data);
    };

    getData();
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *get* type defenition from external source.

You should describe data structure before using it.

For example:

```
type Asset = {
  price_usd: number;
  data_end: string;
  volume_1mth_usd: number;
  data_orderbook_end: string;
  data_start: string;
  type_is_crypto: number;
  data_quote_start: string;
  asset_id: string;
  volume_1hrs_usd: number;
  data_quote_end: string;
  data_orderbook_start: string;
  data_trade_start: string;
  name: string;
  data_symbols_count: number;
  data_trade_end: string;
  volume_1day_usd: number;
};
```

and then:

```
const data: Asset = await response.json();
```